# How to convert string of multiple time units to a number in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Varchar field in an oracle 10 database that people manually enter duration of time worked.  I need to develop fuzzy logic to convert the information into the unit of hours as a number so that it can be summed in a function.

```
9 HOURS
6.0 Hrs
4.5 hours
14 HOURS 30 MIN
17 HOURS 15 MINUTES
10.75 Days
```

I was playing around with the following code to create an equation but I can't get this to convert to a number.  Has anyone done this before?

```
select 
replace(
    replace (
        replace(
         translate(upper('3 Day 3.2 Hours 6 Min '),'DHMAFBCEFGIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','DHM')
                  , 'H', '*1+'),
              'M', '/60'),
           'D','*24+')       
from dual
```

Comment: There is no easy solution for this unfortunately, its the nature of free text, your best hope is to clean the string as much as possible, but your problem will come when you try to separate each number because of the inconsistent input. - In future I would recommend a selection box of hours and minutes.

Comment: I have had this as well, and there's no true solution, as your users are at least as creative in creating obscure formats, as you're skilled in decoding them :) What worked for me was to develop a nested case statement which caught 95% of the entries and spit that all out into Excel - our users reviewed, filled in the blanks and then I was able to upload and correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the "dirty" way to do this (without changing anything in the current setup). I agree with the others who suggested this is a pretty bad model, best to change it.

How complicated the solution is depends on how much flexibility you are willing to allow in your input (free text). I assumed that numbers can be in any of the formats 3 3.5 3.0 12. 0.3 .33 (but no sign, + or -); a number may be followed by zero or more spaces; any of the time components (restricted to days, hours and minutes) may be present or absent; and the components are "marked" by the first letter of the word that follows them: D, H or M. (So this is also language dependent, another weakness of the system if you allow free text in other languages too.) D, H or M may be upper or lower case and may be followed by any other letters (DAY, Days, dy, dd, etc.)

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select '9 HOURS'              from dual union all
       select '6.0 Hrs'              from dual union all
       select '4.5 hours'            from dual union all
       select '14 HOURS 30 MIN'      from dual union all
       select '17 HOURS 15 MINUTES'  from dual union all
       select '10.75 Days'           from dual union all
       select '.5days 30m'           from dual union all
       select '30. h'                from dual union all
       select '2 days 1 hour 30 min' from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- Use your actual table and column names in the SQL query below.
select str,
       nvl(to_number(regexp_substr(str, '(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*D', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), 0)*24 +
       nvl(to_number(regexp_substr(str, '(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*H', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), 0)    +
       nvl(to_number(regexp_substr(str, '(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*M', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), 0)/60
       as hours_worked
from   inputs;

STR                  HOURS_WORKED
-------------------- ------------
9 HOURS                      9.00
6.0 Hrs                      6.00
4.5 hours                    4.50
14 HOURS 30 MIN             14.50
17 HOURS 15 MINUTES         17.25
10.75 Days                 258.00
.5days 30m                  12.50
30. h                       30.00
2 days 1 hour 30 min        49.50
```

Comment: Thanks mathguy!  I totally agree with you the best thing to do is get them to enforce a consistent value. Already recommended it.  But this will only fix moving forward.  I still need to convert the bad historical data.  Your solution does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to add a new column and update this step by step.

```
ALTER TABLE WORKING_TIME_TABLE ADD (WORKING_INTERVAL INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0));

UPDATE WORKING_TIME_TABLE 
SET WORKING_INTERVAL = REGEXP_REPLACE(WORKING_TIME, 'HOURS$', NULL, 1,1,'i') * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
WHERE WORKING_INTERVAL IS NULL
   AND (REGEXP_LIKE(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+ HOURS$', 'i') 
     OR REGEXP_LIKE(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+\.\d+ HOURS$', 'i')) ;  

UPDATE WORKING_TIME_TABLE 
SET WORKING_INTERVAL = REGEXP_REPLACE(WORKING_TIME, 'Hrs$', NULL, 1,1,'i') * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
WHERE WORKING_INTERVAL IS NULL
   AND (REGEXP_LIKE(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+ Hrs$', 'i')
     OR REGEXP_LIKE(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+\.\d+ Hrs$', 'i') );

UPDATE WORKING_TIME_TABLE 
SET WORKING_INTERVAL = REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+') * INTERVAL '1' HOUR + REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORKING_TIME, '\d+', 1,2) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
WHERE WORKING_INTERVAL IS NULL
   AND REGEXP_LIKE(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+ HOURS \d+ MIN(UTES)?$', 'i');


UPDATE WORKING_TIME_TABLE 
SET WORKING_INTERVAL = REGEXP_SUBSTR(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+\.\d+') * INTERVAL '1' DAY
WHERE WORKING_INTERVAL IS NULL
   AND REGEXP_LIKE(WORKING_TIME, '^\d+\.\d+ Days$', 'i');


etc.
```

And of course, after you have successfully updated all `WORKING_INT` change your application to enforce proper interval values!

Comment: Can you check this demo, is returning null. http://rextester.com/KGA63411

Comment: Please see my updated statements, now I caught all. I was just too quick and lazy (and wanted to leave some brain work for you :-))

Comment: Note that, for example, the OR at the end of the first query can be moved within the regular expression (resulting in more efficient processing): `'^\d+(\.\d+)?'` makes the fractional part optional.